# column level permissions in the sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-server

In the sharepoint 2013 list,is there any way possible that i can put some permissions on out of the box attachment column . As per my requirement , the documents which are getting uploaded should only be editable to the author of the item and not to anyone else .

Comment: rest fields can be edited by someone else?

Comment: @iStrange , yes they can be . but not the attachments column . the problem is  someone is uploading some documents and other user is opening that attachment and making the changes . is there any way we can restrict the attached file from saving on the server , because by default it saves the file on to the server itself . but it should not be

Answer (score 0):

No, not out-of-the-box. There are third party solutions for this.

One approach could be (even though I haven't tested it on attachments) to use two separate lists where one has read access and connect them with a lookup column. In that case the looked up column should be visible, but not editable.